# String comparison in shell script with an OR condition

Tags: shell

I have written the following shell script.

```
if [ "$LOCALE" == "US" ]
then
   #do something

elif [ "$LOCALE" == "DE" || "$LOCALE" == "FR" || "$LOCALE" == "IT" || "$LOCALE" == "UK" ]
then
   #do something else.
fi
```

It is giving me the error  `[: missing ]`. Can some one explain me what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell's `if` runs a command (or more technically, a "pipeline", as in this example):

```
if ls | grep xyzzy; then cmd1; cmd2; cmd3; fi
```

The exit-status of the command determines whether the `then` part gets run (or an `else` part if any).  If the pipeline "succeeds", i.e., exits zero—as this one does if a file is at least partly named `xyzzy`—the "then" parts get run.

The `[` command ... is a command!  (It's built-in to all modern shell variants for speed, but it can be run as an ordinary command.)

```
sh-3.2$ [ a == b ]
sh-3.2$
```

The `[` command reads arguments and demands that they end with `]`:

```
sh-3.2$ [
sh: [: missing `]'
sh-3.2$
```

This is the error you're getting, because in `sh` syntax, `prog1 || prog2` means to first run `prog1`, then only if it "fails" (exits non-zero), run `prog2`.  So:

```
prog1 arg || grep xyzzy somefile
```

only runs the `grep` if `prog1` fails.  Hence, in turn:

```
[ x || grep xyzzy somefile
```

runs the `grep` if `[` fails (which it does due to the syntax error).

(Aside: I often see people write things like:

```
ls | grep xyzzy
if [ $? = 0 ]; then cmd1; cmd2; cmd3; fi
```

This is unnecessarily long-winded, since `$?` is simply the exit status of the last pipeline, so this is just the same as my first example.  Of course, some might say this stackoverflow answer is unnecessarily long-winded, too. :-) )

To get the `[` program to test multiple conditions, you can use its `-a` ("and") and `-o` ("or") operators.  Then all your testing will be done with a single run of the `[` program:

```
if [ "$LOCALE" == DE -o "$LOCALE" == FR ]; then ...; fi
```

Or, use multiple invocations of the `[` program, but this becomes more difficult here and starts to require parentheses or brackets:

```
([ "$LOCALE" == DE ] || [ "$LOCALE" == FR ]) && (cmd1; cmd2; ...)

{ [ "$LOCALE" == DE ] || [ "$LOCALE" == FR ]; } && { cmd1; cmd2; ...; }

if { [ "$LOCALE" == DE ] || [ "$LOCALE" == FR ]; } then cmd1; cmd2; ... fi
```

(I don't recommend these alternatives: they work, but are unnecessarily hard to read.  If you must use one, the last is probably the least terrible.)

Consider replacing all of these with a `case`:

```
case "$LOCALE" in
DE|FR|IT|UK) cmd1; cmd2; cmd3;;
*) other commands here;;
esac
```

The `case` statement offers glob-style matching.  For example, you can match user answers against mixed upper and lower case:

```
need_answer=true
while $need_answer; do
    echo -n "should I do a thing? (yes/no, default = no) "
    read answer
    case "$answer" in
    [yY]|[yY][eE]|[yY][eE][sS])
        # handle "yes" case here
        need_answer=false;;
    [nN]|[nN][oO]|"")
        # handle "no" case here
        need_answer=false;;
        ;;
    *) echo "please answer yes or no";;
    esac
done
```

The `*` works by glob-matching any input that was not matched earlier, since the various cases are taken linearly and the first match "wins".

---

Some shells (bash is particularly notable) have additional alternative syntaxes available for `if` statements.

Answer (score 2):

Inside `[...]`, use `-a`(and) and `-o`(or):

```
expr1 -a expr2

    True if both expr1 and expr2 are true.

expr1 -o expr2

    True if either expr1 or expr2 is true.
```

---

Inside `[[...]]`, you can use `&&`(and) and `||`(or).